# Unwind, Project, Group nested document

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

I have a class

```
private sealed class IIn
{
    public String iKey;
    public String fi1;
    public String fi2;
    public List<M> ms;

    public sealed class M
    {
        public String mKey;
        public String fm1;
        public String fm2;
        public List<S> ss;

        public sealed class S
        {
            public String fs1;
            public String fs2;
            public String fs3;
        }
    }
}
```

stored in (Atlas) MongoDB. Next, I use the MongoDB Driver C# LINQ implementation

```
var testItems = testCollection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(x => x.iKey.Equals("i1"))
    .Unwind(x => x.ms)
    .Unwind(x => x["ms"]["ss"])
    .Match(x => x["ms"]["ss"]["fs1"].Equals("fs1111"))
    .Project(
    x => new
    {
        iKey = x["iKey"],
        mKey = x["ms"]["mKey"],
        fs1 = x["ms"]["ss"]["fs1"],
        fs3 = x["ms"]["ss"]["fs3"]
    })
    .Match(x => x.fs3.Equals("fs3111"))
    .Group()
    .ToList();
```

to reduce number of documents, unwind, reduce number of Unwound rows, select the fields I need, keep the rows I want. Then I want to group them back into the same nested structure, minus the fields of no interest.

Is this Group-method possible for an Aggregate?

I used this to get one level of nesting.

```
.Group(
    x => x.iKey,
    x => new
    {
        iKey = x.Key,
        ms = x.Select(
            y => new
            {
                mKey = y.mKey,
                fs1 = y.fs1,
                fs3 = y.fs3
            })
    })
```

**Edit**:
I tried AsQueryable.
I could not get SelectMany to propagate iKey & mKey
**Solution**: Using a Select(x=>new{iKey,ms=x.ms.Select(y=>new{y.mKey,ss=y.ss.Select(z=>new{z.fs1,z.fs3})})})
made it work. No Unwind/Group or SelectMany/GroupBy needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Select(x=>new{iKey,ms=x.ms.Select(y=>new{y.mKey,ss=y.ss.Select(z=>new{z.fs1,z.fs3})})})
```